arr_to_image changes the grayscale images
When processing images, I encountered strange behavior when converting a PIL gray image to a NumPy array.
Here is a small code that loads a gray image image.
from keras.utils import img_to_array, array_to_img
a = keras.utils.load_img(img_src + "/00000.jpg")
b = img_to_array(a)
c = array_to_img(b) d = img_to_array(c)

After uploading the image in PIL format, it is displayed normally. The subsequent conversion of it to a NumPy array and back changes the colors.
This screenshot shows the contents of the arrays:

I've tried different image loading modes (RGB,greyscale), dtype type conversion - nothing helps.
I want to be able to save the image after conversion in its original form.
Original image:

After conversion:


You need set parameter scale=False in tf.keras.utils.array_to_img()

array_to_img rescales images by default (see default value in the documentation: scale=True). This means, when your array (in this case the variable b) does not have a value range between 0 and 255, it will be rescaled. Therefore, you need to deactivate the scaling by setting the scale parameter to false:
c = array_to_img(b, scale=False)

